# Python regex with question mark literal

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm using Django's URLconf, the URL I will receive is `/?code=authenticationcode`

I want to match the URL using `r'^\?code=(?P<code>.*)$'` , but it doesn't work.

Then I found out it is the problem of '?'.

Becuase I tried to match `/aaa?aaa` using `r'aaa\?aaa'` `r'aaa\\?aaa'` even `r'aaa.*aaa'` , all failed, but it works when it's "+" or any other character.

How to match the '?', is it special?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> s="aaa?aaa"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'aaa\?aaa', s)
['aaa?aaa']
```

The reason `/aaa?aaa` won't match inside your URL is because a `?` begins a new GET query.

So, the matchable part of the URL is only up to the first 'aaa'. The remaining '?aaa' is a new *query string* separated by the '?' mark, containing a variable "aaa" being passed as a GET parameter.

What you *can* do here is encode the variable before it makes its way into the URL. The encoded form of `?` is `%3F`.

---

You should also not match a GET query such as `/?code=authenticationcode` using regex at all. Instead, match your URL up to `/` using `r'^$'`. Django will pass the variable `code` as a GET parameter to the `request` object, which you can obtain in your view using `request.GET.get('code')`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to use `?` in a URL as a variable value. The `?` indicates that there are variables coming in.

Like: `http://www.example.com?variable=1&another_variable=2`

Replace it or escape it. Here's some nice [documentation](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Django's `urls.py` does not parse query strings, so there is no way to get this information at the `urls.py` file.

Instead, parse it in your view:

```
def foo(request):
   code = request.GET.get('code')
   if code:
      # do stuff
   else:
      # No code!
```

Answer (score 0):

"How to match the '?', is it special?"
Yes, but you are properly escaping it by using the backslash. I do not see where you have accounted for the leading forward slash, though. That bit just needs to be added in:

```
r'^/\?code=(?P<code>.*)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

supress the regex metacharacters with `[]`

```
>>> s
'/?code=authenticationcode'
>>> r=re.compile(r'^/[?]code=(.+)')
>>> m=r.match(s)
>>> m.groups()
('authenticationcode',)
```

Comment: What happens when (s)he decides to "suppress" the metacharacters in this manner: `[^?$]`? Escaping would be the better approach.