# Python Pandas: How to replace string contain "?"

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, str-replace

I have a Python 2.7 Pandas Data frame like following:

```
Id      Title             URL
Id-1    Bruce Almighty    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VGyTOGxyVA
Id-2    Superhero Movie   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BnXz-7-y-o
Id-3    Taken             https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjbfiOERDYs
Id-4    Forest Gump       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJFkCJySHdY&t=524s
```

I want to replace part of string "?v=" with some other string, for example "ppp"from the column "URL". I tried by normal replace command:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace('?v=', 'ppp')
```

but got following error.

```
error: nothing to repeat.
```

When I try by replacing only one character, for example:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace('?', 'ppp')
```

it works fine. Why it didn't work when I try to replace string "?v=" ?

Comment: you're trying to replace '?=v' instead of '?v='

Comment: thanks. edited the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need escape `?` by `\`:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace('\?v=', 'ppp')
print (df)
     Id            Title                                                URL
0  Id-1   Bruce Almighty        https://www.youtube.com/watchppp5VGyTOGxyVA
1  Id-2  Superhero Movie        https://www.youtube.com/watchppp3BnXz-7-y-o
2  Id-3            Taken        https://www.youtube.com/watchpppvjbfiOERDYs
3  Id-4      Forest Gump  https://www.youtube.com/watchpppeJFkCJySHdY&t=...
```

Another solution with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].replace('\?v=', 'ppp', regex=True)
print (df)
     Id            Title                                                URL
0  Id-1   Bruce Almighty        https://www.youtube.com/watchppp5VGyTOGxyVA
1  Id-2  Superhero Movie        https://www.youtube.com/watchppp3BnXz-7-y-o
2  Id-3            Taken        https://www.youtube.com/watchpppvjbfiOERDYs
3  Id-4      Forest Gump  https://www.youtube.com/watchpppeJFkCJySHdY&t=...
```

Comment: Thanks. But why did it work when I try to replace only "?" character?

Comment: Because it is special regex character. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766953/python-regex-with-question-mark-literal).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can instruct Pandas that you are doing a standard (not RegEx) replace:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.replace('?v=', 'ppp', regex=False)
```