# Python Error: nothing to repeat at position 4

Tags: python, filter, error-handling

I am trying to filter 2 columns of a Dataframe **LoanData**

The two columns are namely **LengthofHistoryGrid** and **ASSET_CLASS_CD**

The Python Code I tried is as below

```
LoanData_Greaterthan11 = LoanData[(LoanData['LengthofHistoryGrid']>=12) & (LoanData['ASSET_CLASS_CD'].str.contains('S|M|?|-1|1|NaN'))]
```

However, it is throwing the error nothing to repeat at position 4

Looked at Various posts at Stack Overflow which suggest it is a Python Bug also most posts suggests that this error is mostly for Regex problems but I am getting this for Dataframe Filter

How do I overcome this problem? or is there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't you know that you're using a regex in the dataframe filter?

Answer (score 2):

`.str.contains` in Pandas uses regex (unless `regex=False` is passed), and you wrote `.contains('S|M|?|-1|1|NaN')`.

`?` here is interpreted as "one or none" quantifier for previous symbol or group, and previous symbol is `|` which is a separator and not a matching character, so the quantifier position is invalid. So you need to escape the question mark, as per [Python regex with question mark literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766953/python-regex-with-question-mark-literal):

```py
LoanData_Greaterthan11 = LoanData[(LoanData['LengthofHistoryGrid']>=12) & (LoanData['ASSET_CLASS_CD'].str.contains(r'S|M|\?|-1|1|NaN'))]
```